# ggplot gradientn fill based on data value with shape specified

Tags: r, ggplot2

In the ggplot2 [example for scale_gradientn](http://had.co.nz/ggplot2/scale_gradientn.html) (second last graphic):

```
dsub <- subset(diamonds, x > 5 & x < 6 & y > 5 & y < 6) 
dsub$diff <- with(dsub, sqrt(abs(x-y))* sign(x-y)) 
(d <- qplot(x, y, data=dsub, colour=diff))

max_val <- max(abs(dsub$diff)) 
values <- seq(-max_val, max_val, length = 11) 
d + scale_colour_gradientn(colours = topo.colors(10), values = values, rescale = FALSE)
```

How can I fill according to a data value when using a "shape" symbol, i.e.:

```
(d <- qplot(x, y, data=dsub, fill=diff, colour="black", shape=21)) # Does not work
```

but with a black border and data-based fill rather than with a data-based border colour?

EDIT:

Proposed solutions are not quite working. All I need is to be able to use shape=21 with the example I show above, to get the same fill colour, but with a black border, i.e. this:

```
dsub <- subset(diamonds, x > 5 & x < 6 & y > 5 & y < 6) 
dsub$diff <- with(dsub, sqrt(abs(x-y))* sign(x-y))
max_val <- max(abs(dsub$diff))
values <- seq(-max_val, max_val, length = 11)

ggplot(dsub) +
    geom_point(aes(x=x,y=y, data=dsub, colour=diff), size=3) +
    scale_colour_gradientn(colours = topo.colors(10), values = values, rescale = FALSE)
```

but using shape=21 so that there is a black border and the fill is the same. This colours the outline, instead of the fill:

```
ggplot(dsub) +
    geom_point(aes(x=x,y=y, data=dsub, colour=diff), size=3, shape=21) +
    scale_colour_gradientn(colours = topo.colors(10), values = values, rescale = FALSE)
```

and this does not fill correctly:

```
ggplot(dsub) +
geom_point(aes(x=x,y=y, data=dsub, fill=diff), size=3, shape=21) +
scale_colour_gradientn(colours = topo.colors(10), values = values, rescale = FALSE)
```

Comment: PS in the code you provide line 6 produces an error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As in the code shown by user1317221_G, the solution is to use `scale_fill_gradientn`, not `scale_color_gradientn`:

```
ggplot(dsub) +
    geom_point(aes(x=x,y=y,fill=diff), colour="black", size=3, shape=21) +
    scale_fill_gradientn(colours = topo.colors(10), values=values, rescale=FALSE)
```

Answer (score 1):

using ggplot it would be:

```
d<-ggplot(dsub,aes(x=x,y=y,group=diff,fill=diff))
d+geom_point(colour="black",size=3,shape=21)
```

[image]

**EDIT**

```
d<-ggplot(dsub,aes(x=x,y=y,group=diff,fill=diff))
e<- d + geom_point(colour="black",size=3,shape=21)
e + scale_fill_gradientn(colours=topo.colors(10))
```

[image]

Also pretending that you have another layer somewhere e.g. `geom_tile` or something as you mentioned in your comment,  here is an example with an extra `geom_line` layer which I have broken down into separate components to make it clear:

```
d<-ggplot(dsub,aes(x=x,y=y,group=diff,fill=diff))
e<-d+geom_line()
g<- e + geom_point(colour="black",size=3,shape=21)
g + scale_fill_gradientn(colours=topo.colors(10))
```

Comment: And using qplot you need qplot(x, y, data=dsub, fill=diff, colour=I("black"), shape=I(21)) .  The trick is those I() functions around things that may or may not be aesthetic mappings.  This is a good example I think of when qplot turns out to not be that easy after all and the ggplot version is more intuitive.

Comment: So how do I do this if the points are a second layer in an existing ggplot, i.e. via a geom_points() call?

Comment: not sure what you mean @Benjamin. Do you mean like this: `d<-ggplot(dsub,aes(x=x,y=y,group=diff,fill=diff));e<-d+geom_line(); e + geom_point(colour="black",size=3,shape=21)`

Comment: I am plotting a geom_tile() layer first, so the ggplot() call refers to that data, different data than what I am using for the geom_point() call. That means I can't specify the group and fill in the ggplot() call. Is there a way to specify all the params through the geom_point() call?

Comment: you can specify different data sets for each `geom` So you can have `geom_tile(data1,....) + geom_point(data=data2,..)`

Comment: Getting there, but the colour is not like in the example I listed... How can I apply scale_colour_gradientn after what you suggest?

Comment: But how do you do it when the ggplot() call defines the data used in geom_line() rather than the data used in geom_point()?

Comment: Thanks for your help. Using scale_fill_gradientn rather than scale_colour_gradientn worked.